# SPFx extension customizer JS files is not loading on production tenant of my SharePoint Online site

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions, sharepoint-framework

I have two different tenant, one is for development things and another for production.

I have developed one SPFx extension and deployed on development and production site. It was working perfectly fine on both environment but suddenly 2 days ago it stopped working on production environment.

I tried to troubleshoot the issue and observed that SPFx customizer files are not loading on production site.

Can someone please suggest, why this has happened and what could be the possible solution for such issue.